# JavaFX + afterburnerfx + trayicon - Lost injection after stage close/hide

Tags: java, swing, javafx-8

I'm trying to create an application using JavaFX and Swing for TrayIcon.

On load, i check if the user already exists:

```
NewuserView view = new NewuserView();
NewuserPresenter presenter = (NewuserPresenter)view.getPresenter();

User user = presenter.getUser();

    if(user.getUsername() == null) {
        Scene scene = new Scene(view.getView());
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    } else {
        TrayIconManager.minimizeToTray();
    }
```

`NewuserPresenter` have an `@Inject User user` with default constructor, and all works fine (i've placed a log in it, and will be called).

If the user is already exists, the minimizeToTray() do:

```
javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(TrayIconManager::doAppToTray);
private static void doApptoTray() {
   ....
   stage.close(); // or stage.hide(), no difference
}
```

Now the application is minimized and, when i call an action on it (for example., create event) the presenter have an `@Inject User user` (exactly like `NewuserView`).

```
public NewEventPresenter implements Initializable {
@Inject
    private User user;

 @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
     //user is null there
   }
}
```

This presenter is loaded exactly in the same way as before:

```
private static void showNewEventRegistration() {
    NeweventView newEventView = new NeweventView();
    Scene scene = new Scene(newEventView.getView());
    TrayIconManager.stage.setScene(scene);

    TrayIconManager.stage.show();
}
```

The `showNewEventRegistration` is loaded with `Platform.runLater` , because must run on FX Application Thread.

But at this point, the user is null.

The first time i show the stage, `User` is injected. The next time i show again the stage (because was hidden/closed to run the application on tray) the `User` is null.

User should be a `@Singleton`, i've tried with that annotation and without, but no difference.... even null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think to have solved this:

I was using `com.google.inject.Inject` in my presenter, and not `javax.inject.Inject`